# lodash filter deeply nested objects returning array of those objects

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to return an array of objects that are deeply nested in another array. Here is a sample object with arrays:

```
payment = {
"id": 1,
"tickets" = [{
  "id": 1,
  "ticketItems": [{item1}, {item2}, {item3}]
  },
  {"id": 2",
  "ticketItems":  [{item4}, {item5}, {item6}]
  }]}
```

Using lodash I would like to return an array of just items 1-6 without the parent objects. I've tried:

```
var items = _.filter(payment.tickets, {'ticketItems'});
```

But that doesn't return an array of ticketItems. All the examples I've found use a condition like "id: 1", but I want all of the ticketItems, not just those matching a condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` (or lodash's `_.flatMap()`) and return the `ticketItems` from each `tickets` object:

```js
const payment = {"id":1,"tickets":[{"id":1,"ticketItems":[{"item1":1},{"item2":2},{"item3":3}]},{"id":2,"ticketItems":[{"item4":4},{"item5":5},{"item6":6}]}]}

const result = payment.tickets.flatMap(o => o.ticketItems)

console.log(result)
```

And the same solution with lodash's `_.flatMap()`:

```js
const payment = {"id":1,"tickets":[{"id":1,"ticketItems":[{"item1":1},{"item2":2},{"item3":3}]},{"id":2,"ticketItems":[{"item4":4},{"item5":5},{"item6":6}]}]}

const result = _.flatMap(payment.tickets, 'ticketItems')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```